# How to resolve modular dependency in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have app module and also another module
both in gradle:
app.gradle 
somemodule.gradle
I have " compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' " in both module and after run gradle shows this error:

> Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define /BuildConfig;

Comment: Can you show your project structure ? And in particular your both gradle files.

Comment: Sometimes this can be resolved by simply rebuilding — I just ran into this today. If you've tried that, then as @SharpEdge said, we'll need to see more.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid defining dependencies in modules, instead define them at project level. First of all, place all your project’s dependencies (of all modules) inside a Gradle file like **libraries.gradle**:

```
ext {

   minSdkVersion = 9
   compileSdkVersion = 25
   buildToolsVersion = "25.0.0"

   //Android
   androidSupportVersion = "25.0.0"
   butterknifeVersion = "8.0.1"

/*...*/

libraries = [

        androidSupport   : "com.android.support:support-v4:${androidSupportVersion}",
        appCompat        : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${androidSupportVersion}",
        designSupport    : "com.android.support:design:${androidSupportVersion}",

        /*...*/

        ]



}
```

then add it to your project main **build.gradle** file (the last line):

```
buildscript {

repositories {

    jcenter()

}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    /*...*/

  }

}

apply from: "./libraries.gradle"
```

and finally, use it in your app's modules **build.gradle** files (an example of how to):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
/*...*/

android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

  /*...*/
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':your-base-module-name')

    compile rootProject.ext.libraries.appCompat
    compile rootProject.ext.libraries.androidSupport
    compile rootProject.ext.libraries.designSupport

    /*...*/
}
```

This will avoid duplicate or conflicting dependencies across all modules.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes we import different versions from google products/APIs. So,
>   try to organize your gradle file to solve this kind of issues

You can also refer [this link](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/ad6672902464ee2392d0) to understand managing the support libraries in a multi-module project